How to Fix Width and Height Not Applying in Login Modal?
The modal in the first code block is the same as LoginModal, but even though I specified the width and height in LoginModal (as shown in the second code block), the width and height are not being applied as expected.
ModalProvider
"use client";
import { useModalStore } from "@/zustand/modalStore/modalStore";
import React, { PropsWithChildren } from "react";

function ModalProvider({ children }: PropsWithChildren) {
  const modal = useModalStore((state) => state.modal);
  const closeModal = useModalStore((state) => state.closeModal);

  return (
    <>
      {modal ? (
        <div
          className="fixed top-0 left-0 right-0 bottom-0 z-50 bg-black/80"
          onClick={() => closeModal()}
        >
          {modal}
        </div>
      ) : (
        modal
      )}
      {children};
    </>
  );
}

export default ModalProvider;


LogInModal
import React from "react";

function LoginModal() {
  return (
    <div className="absolute bg-white w-[500px] h-[530px] rounded-md">
      로그인 모달입니다.
    </div>
  );
}

export default LoginModal;

I tried modifying the CSS code, but it didn’t work.
